# Looking for a documentary on history of communication

Tags: communication

I am looking for a documentary on the history of communication technologies.

I found one particular [documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gX9cCmUcjPM) but I'm trying to figure out its title.

The actual video is in French and appears to be a translation of a discovery channel documentary. The title is translated as "Histoire d'inventions", but I wasn't able to find anything while searching for this (or the corresponding English translation in google). I speak French, but hearing the French voice on top of the original version is quite annoying and I was hoping to find if this is part of a bigger series.

Any other good documentary on the subject will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about videos but there is an excellent book:  Ludvík Souček, The story of communications (English translation from the Czech).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was the tenth (and last) programme in a 2009 (or 2007 according to some sources) series called [Inventing History](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1135373/), presented by the Dutch actor and writer [Ronald Top](http://ronaldtop.com/about/).

There were 10 episodes in all. As you guessed, the programmes were originally recorded in English. The titles of the 10 episodes were:

- Furniture
- Writing
- Time
- Safe and Sound
- Personal Transport
- Money
- Light
- Keeping Warm
- Home Entertainment
- Communication